# Linux восстановление данных

Tags: linux, восстановление

Здравствуйте! Очень нужна помощь, из ISP по глупости был удален пользователь, а вместе с ним и папка www в /var. Корзины в системе нет. Посоветуйте что-нибудь для восстановления данных с её структурой. Гуглил по данной теме, находил testdisk и photorec, но они могут просто восстановить файлы без их оригинального названия и структуры. Бекапов нет не у кого.

Comment: бекапы? у нормального IPS они обычно есть

Comment: Нет бекапов никаких.

Comment: мне в подобной ситуации помог ext4magic, но у меня была удалена папка на внешнем hdd и после удаления диск сразу был в ro перемонтирован

Comment: В общем, я так понял, нет смысла даже пытаться.

Comment: Забудьте, всё пропало!

Comment: Я уже вручную восстановил все данные, так что вопрос можно закрывать.